# Talend - tmysqlcommit with tmysqloutput - error

Tags: mysql, talend

I have a talend job, with the following sequence

tmssqlinput --> tmap --> tmysqloutput
|onsubjobok
tmssqlrow

I do want the autocommit option in tmysqloutput. I want to use the tmysqlcommit, but how should I used it? I have already determined the connection details in tmysqloutput. If I connect tmysqloutput to tmysqlcommit, I get an error in the 'Component list' of tmysqloutput. It is expecting a value there and its drop down with no values in it

How do I use tmysqlcommit in this scenario?

Thanks in advance
Rathi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tMysqlCommit can only be used with tMysqlConnection, that's why you're getting an error as there are non connection components to be selected in the drop down list. It should be like this :

```
tMysqlConnection -- OnSubJobOk -- tMysqlInput -- tMap -- tMysqlOutput -- OnComponentOk -- tMysqlCommit
```

And you should handle insert errors like this :

```
<<Same subjob>> -- tMysqlOutput -- OnComponentError -- tMysqlRollback
```

Comment: Thanks a lot iMezouar. However, I have 15+ jobs running in parallel. And each job has the design like I have mentioned here on this topic. So, if 15+ jobs run in parallel, will there be any issue of opening/closing of mysql connection that many a times  in parallel

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem, each job will open/close its own connection. Unless you have a very limited connection pool in your MySQL instance (less than 15) ?

Comment: Hi, select @@max_connections gives 151. So another question, previously I wasnt using tmysqlcommit and tmysqlconnection, I used to configure every mysql component with context variable. The job design was still the same, 15+ jobs running in parallel. So, even in this scenario, is talend opening and closing mysql connection in every mysql component in 15+ jobs accessing mysql?

Comment: Yes. Actually, in your old design, Talend will make a MySQL connection for every mysql component (tMysqlInput, tMysqlOutput, tMysqlRow). Using a tMysqlConnection, Talend only makes one connection per job, and uses it for all your mysql components. So, if you weren't running into connection limitations with your old design, then you are less likely to get them by using a shared connection.

Comment: Thanks iMezouar, that answers my questions !!

Comment: Great ! Glad I could help you :)